Black background of copied and pasted image Java Swing
I try to copy a molecule image in ChemDraw (it is like Incscape to draw molecules) and paste it to my Swing GUI. I use something like that.
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Demo1 extends JFrame {
    public Demo1() throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        imageLabel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 180));
        add(imageLabel);
        setSize(200, 180);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                new Demo1();
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
            }
        });
    }
}

The resulted image seems OK but transparent area turned into black.
Copied and pasted images
It is very similar to problem in this question. The solution was “to use a custom system flavor which understands the mimetype of 'image\x-emf', strip first 8 bytes and write the remaining content as Bufferred image”. So, I tried to investigate clipboard content. Inside Clipboard shows the following:
Inside Clipboard output
I tried to get every object, convert it to String and to BufferedImage using this code
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Demo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] formats = new String[] { "ChemDraw Interchange Format", "Embed Source",
                "Object Descriptor", "CF_ENHMETAFILE", "CF_METAFILEPICT", "ChemDraw Structure Data",
                "MDLSK", "MDLCT", "SMILES", "SLNSTRING" };

        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        SystemFlavorMap systemFlavorMap = (SystemFlavorMap) SystemFlavorMap.getDefaultFlavorMap();
        int i = 0;
        for (String format : formats) {
            // The exact MIME is not important for getting from clipboard. There are could
            // be anything
            DataFlavor newDataFlavor = new DataFlavor(
                    "app/format" + (i++) + ";class=java.io.InputStream", format);
            systemFlavorMap.addFlavorForUnencodedNative(format, newDataFlavor);
        }
        Transferable transferable = clipboard.getContents(null);
        i = 0;
        for (String format : formats) {
            System.out.println(format);
            DataFlavor newDataFlavor = new DataFlavor(
                    "app/format" + (i++) + ";class=java.io.InputStream", format);
            if (transferable.isDataFlavorSupported(newDataFlavor)) {
//              Only ENHMETAFILE and METAFILEPICT didn't take "true"
                System.out.println(true);
                try {
                    InputStream data = (InputStream) clipboard.getData(newDataFlavor);
                    byte[] bytes = data.readAllBytes();
                    System.out.print(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    System.out.print("\n\n");

//                  Trying to make image
                    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
//                  I didn't have any success(
                    if (image != null) System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

CF_ENHMETAFILE and CF_METAFILEPICT is not accessible by that way.
Object Descriptor is something constant for any copied molecule so it is not an image.
MDLCT, SMILES and SLNSTRING is just a textual representation of molecular structure. As far as I understand MDLSK is also something like that.
ChemDraw Interchange Format is ChemDraw Exchange format that is obvious due to first 8 bytes (VjCD0100). It is not an image.
Embed source is pretty interesting. I can’t understand everything but I see that there is something in the beginning and after that just what was in “ChemDraw Interchange Format” object. I think it could be an object to make OLE because I can paste molecular structure in Office program and after that it can be transferred to ChemDraw using double click.
So, I don’t understand where is the image. It is interesting that in contrast to Swing, JavaFX can’t get any image, for example:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Demo3 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        System.out.print(clipboard.hasImage()); // Prints false     
        Platform.exit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


Consider download the image and remove the background using your computer's photo editor. Images with transparent background normally tend to have a black background when you use it on any place

Chemdraw has a png export function, perhaps it would be better to ask your users to use that and provide a png import function in your app, rather than request the users to perform copy-and-paste, which appears difficult for you to support.

I wonder if your 'problem types' are some kind of Windows metafile. which are, iirc, some kind of vector format? Vector drawing would make sense for that sort of subject matter. If so, I then wonder if you might not be able to paste them into a Batik Swing window?

The JavaFX code seems odd. What are you doing copying the image then running the code? I just feel like you would need to have some type of listener to capture the Clipboard correctly. I don't use it much, so I don't know.

bit strange, despite first code not compiling, if corrected I get the transparent image without black background, the transparent part is displayed with the background color of the frame (or its content pane to be exact) but I copied the image from GIMP ( examples with default background and with yellow background screenshot )

@user85421 Yes, it works well if I copy from Inkscape. It is not a surprise because there are a PNG object in the system clipboard after copying. I expect it works the same in case of GIMP. But when I copy from ChemDraw there are no something like a PNG object.

Looks like I was correct about the type of source image. You might go even further and not only preserve transparency but preserve the actual paths. I see FOP supports that mimetype

@g00se I think you are right. After coping from ChemDraw there is a vector image in the clipboard.  For example, I can paste it into Inkscape and it will be a vector image. Also I can see that pasted image in Word stored as .emf file. But I don't know how to get a vector image from the clipboard. Using clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor) gives a raster image.
